# All EVEN values at the beginning, and odds at the end in Node list

Tags: c#, linked-list

That's High School question type, therefore using "Heavy wepones" is not allowed, also not allowed to use with array, the question is: Suuppose I have al list of nodes I should put all nodes with even values at the beginig of the list and all nodes with odd values I should put at the end of the list, i.e:

`3,2,7,6,9,4` ---> `2,6,4,3,7,9`

Node class:

```
public class Node
{
    public int value;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(int value, Node next)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void SetNext( Node next)
    {           
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void SetValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node GetNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
       return this.value;
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
    Node n1 = new Node(3);
    Node n2 = new Node(2);
    Node n3 = new Node(1);
    Node n4 = new Node(4);
    Node n5 = new Node(9);
    Node n6 = new Node(6);

    n1.SetNext(n2);
    n2.SetNext(n3);
    n3.SetNext(n4);
    n4.SetNext(n5);
    n5.SetNext(n6);
    Ex(n1); // Invoking the function
```

I have started something like:

```
 private void Ex(Node list)
        {
            Node temp = list;        
            while (temp != null)
            {
                if (temp.GetValue() % 2 == 0)
                {

                }
            }          
        }
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-even-and-odd-elements-in-a-linked-list/

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Hi, why the downvote, I don't want to be blocked

Comment: the code from the link doesn't work, it gives a list with only odd values

Comment: @BugFixer,I am not a downvoter; I just pasted program from GfG. By end of today I will provide my answer

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Ok, I will wait for your answer

Comment: I upvoted, not because you said but I liked your problem; You should put some efforts and show us what you tried so far to resolve your problem

Comment: I tried to create new list but it didn't worked, it always gave me new list with length of 2